# graphics shows me the figures with a black background, but when they are saved in the folder I defined, they are saved with a white background

Tags: matlab-figure

[image]

Why at the time of graphing shows me the figures with a black background, but when they are saved in the folder I defined, they are saved with a white background?
i am using:

```
figure(1)
pcolor(X./1000,Y./1000,real(Var))
title(['RR [mm/h] - ', datestr(time(ii)), ' EL = ' ,num2str(elv)])
shading flat
caxis([0 30])
axis([-60 60 -60 60])
colorbar
colormap(jet)
set(gca,'Color','k')
path='A:\Documentos\IGP\Radar PX_1000\Plots\260218\';
gfile=[path,'R',datestr(time(ii),'ddmmyy_HHMMSS')]
print(gfile,'-dpng','-r300')
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` does some funny things to figures when it saves them (I believe using a white background is one of them). If you're looking to replicate what the image looks like in final output, I'd recommend [export_fig](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig).  From the documentation at the link:

> Note that the background color and figure dimensions are reproduced (the latter approximately, and ignoring cropping & magnification) in the output file.